# CSS selector for class and attribute together

Tags: css, styles

I've currently got a few buttons with the `.continue` class on a webpage, structured with the following code:

```
<div class="continue" data-section="1">
    Continue
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="continueArrow1"></i>
</div>
```

Each of the continue buttons have a different "data-section" values, and are also placed against different backgrounds on the webpage. I'm wondering if there is a way I am able to target one of these continue button `div`s that have a certain `data-section` value, and change the styling of those who match.

Something like:

```
.continue:data-section=1{
    //css that styles button with data-section1
}

.continue:data-section=2{
    //css that styles button with data-section2
}
```

Obviously I could always just give them different IDs, but that leads to a lot of code duplication for the JS and JQuery animations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector:

```
.continue[data-section="1"] {
    ...
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.continue[data-section="2"] {
    background: red;
}

/*We can combine this selector with other selectors as we normally would:*/
.continue[data-section="2"]:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="continue" data-section="1"></div>
<div class="continue" data-section="2"></div>
<div class="continue" data-section="3"></div>
<div class="continue" data-section="4"></div>
<div class="continue" data-section="5"></div>
```

**Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)**